# Не загружается симулятор UWP после обновления Creators Update 1709 (VS 2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Бесконечная загрузка симулятора, видно бегущие точки и дальше ничего. P.S вчера установил обновление Creators Update 1709, приложение скомпилировалось без ошибок и работает открытием .exe файла, используется VS 2017 Community и Windows 10 Home для одного языка

Answer (score 0):

Помогало удаление эмуляторов из Hyper-V и удаление сетевого адаптера, созданного для эмуляторов. При первом запуске всё заново создастся.